# Is it possible to have nested objects in Angular resource?

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, restful-url, angular-resource

I'm building an RESTful API. I have a Person object in my model and every Person object has a IsStarred boolean property. So, for the Person objects, I've created a "people" resource that looks like this:

```
// Performs CRUD operations on this resource.
api/people/:id
```

In order to preserve the RESTful model, I have the following resource that changes the IsStarred property of a given Person object:

```
// POST method sets IsStarred property to true, while DELETE method sets it to false.
// Example: POST api/people/2/star => Sets IsStarred = true to Person with Id == 2
// DELETE api/people/2/star => Sets IsStarred = false to Person with Id == 2
api/people/:id/star
```

Now, I want to use the same strucutre in an Angular app, using $resource. I already have a Person resource that looks like this:

```
var Person= $resource('api/people/:id', { id: '@id' });
```

And I can use this Person resource in the well-known way.

By the way, now if I decide to edit the resource and make it look like this:

```
var Person= $resource('api/people/:id/star', { id: '@id' });
```

I can now use only the (un)star functionality, meaning I would have to make two different resources. Is this my only option or there's another one?

Comment: What I generally do is -> make the "star" also an optional param as :star. Then I just pass it in the object as a param. Works quite well.

Comment: @wtflux - yeap, thanks, I think Petr's answer is presenting exactly what you are saying, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additional param:

```
var Person = $resource('api/people/:id:mode', { id: '@id'}, 
    get : {method : 'GET', params : {mode : ''}}, 
    post : {method : 'POST', params : {mode : '/star'}});
```